# Xcode Application Loader upload error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

When I upload my app to the App Store, an error occurred.

So I tried uploading it with the Application Loader. I got the same error again.

My XCode version is Version 9.1 (9B55).

Here is the detailed error message:

[image]

**Does anyone know how to solve it?**

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please post more details, like the error message, as formatted text in the body of your question. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better results using this site. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

emmm. I found a way and tried. it worked.

open the Teminal and run

```
cd ~  
mv .itmstransporter/ .old_itmstransporter/  
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"
```

you can view https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76803